# Replace word from multiple filenames

Tags: sed, grep, rename

I have this filename:

```
BG60UFL-GBR_EarlsdonMSIN_2017-12-18_22-19-44-785_APPROACH.jpg
```

It needs to be replaced with whis:

```
BG60UFL-GBR__2017-12-18_22-19-44-785.jpg
```

This is what I tried:

```
sed 's#\\Earlsdon##g' file1 >  file2
```

Comment: To explain why yours didn't work: `sed` operates on the _contents_ of the file, not the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
rename 's/^(BG60UFL-GBR_)\w+(_(\d|-|_)+)_\w+\.jpg/$1$2.jpg/' *.jpg
```

I don't know which parts are variable, then I explain you a little bit and maybe you have change to adapt a little bit.

`rename` is a command of linux and in the first parameter is the regex to get the matching files and the name what you want. The second parameter is the file or files that you want to rename.
In my example you can see this:

1. `^(BG60UFL-GBR_)\w+(_(\d|-|_)+)_\w+\.jpg`. I'm using the regex to get the parts that I want to the new name. The parts inside of `()` are groups and you can use it in the second part. Then I'm saving the parts that I want.
2. `$1$2.jpg` This is the new name.
   `$1` is the first part inside `()`, in this case: `BG60UFL-GBR_`.
   `$2` is `_2017-12-18_22-19-44-785`
3. `*.jpg` is the pattern that means (I want to apply this in all files with the extension.jpg in the current directory)

Comment: bulk rename utility app helped me.. Thanks